# SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: (conn=71) Unknown column 'gp_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-error-1054

Not sure what is going on here, or I'm just going blind from working on the same project for so long... So here's the question.... Something extremely simple..

DB: Maria 10.4.24
PHP: 8.1.6

If I run this query in DBeaver or PHPMyAdmin or PHP

```
DELETE FROM gps WHERE gp_id = 5
```

I get

```
SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: (conn=71) Unknown column 'gp_id' in 'field list'
```

This just stopped working, it was working, but just stopped....

If I rename the column to bob_id and run DELETE FROM gps WHERE bob_id = 5; it works...

Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess that your table did not have a column named `gp_id`, no matter how much you were convinced it did. If you change the column name back to `gp_id`, does it work now?

Comment: I wouldn't have been able to rename the column from gp_id to bob_id if it didn't exist. It's visible in phpstorm, DBeaver, HeidiSql, DbSchema & phpmyadmin.... Even selecting delete on any row in phpmyadmin results in the same error. If I renaming the column back to gp_id, it no longer works again... Weird...

Comment: I'm just going to re-write the sql for building the tables and relationships, something in there probably...

Comment: The only other idea I can think of is that `gp_id` is not the same as `ɡр_іԁ`. There are a lot of characters in Unicode that look almost identical to familiar ASCII characters, but they are distinct glyphs. See https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp?a=gp_id&r=None

Comment: Found it... A rogue trigger got created by DBSchema...

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER

Instead of just dropping the DB, I deleted all the tables bar the one in question (gps), then tried a delete, it still failed, same error "column not found".

So I went looking for triggers, constraints etc and from somewhere a trigger not known to me got created. This was trying to null the gp_id column in some other table that doesn't have that column in it.

I have foreign key relationship constraints in place to handle this via cascade on delete set to null, I think it must have been DBSchema's doing, it does weird things sometimes.

Dropped the trigger, re-build db and seeded it and all is well in the world once again...

So just an error message with not enough information to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Cases like this is why I don't use any GUI clients for MySQL.

Comment: I like to design visually first, normalise and then take it to code, must have got in there in the early stages.